# Installing Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby, macos

I can't install ruby 1.9.1. I tried installing macports, homebrew, and RVM. I installed macports but somehow when I used the commands it didn't work. Installing homebrew was a problem in of itself. Ditto for RVM.

Can anyone provide step by step instructions on how to do this on a mac leopard.

Geez, didn't think it would be this difficult.

Comment: Most people probably aren't having trouble. Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend figuring out RVM because switching back and forth between different versions of Ruby (and Rails) is a breeze.

If you installed Macports correctly, RVM should be easy to install with the following commands:

```
$ sudo gem install rvm
$ rvm-install
```

If you are having issues with MacPorts, check and see if your PATH is set up properly.  I had to add this line to the top of my .bash_profile file (which is a hidden file in my home directory):

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

You can read more here: http://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell

Once MacPorts and RVM are installed, you can add versions of Ruby like so:

```
$rvm install 1.9.2-head
$rvm install 1.8.7
```

I didn't install 1.9.1 but it's probably '$rvm install 1.9.1'.  Remember not to use 'sudo' to install ruby after you've installed RVM.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Benjamin's [ruby installation instructions](http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard) helped me.